# Android retrofit get json object

Tags: android, web-services, retrofit

I am using retrofit library for a web service that expect request as json and give response as json.

```
public class GitHubClient extends Activity{

private static final String API_URL = "http://10.0.0.32/test";

static class Contributor {
    String login;
    int contributions;
}
public static class Array {
    public String id;
    public String name;
}
class Contributor1 {
    public  Array array;
}
interface Login {
    @POST("/testapp/")
    Contributor1 mu(@Body User user,Callback<Contributor1> callBack);

}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new myasyncclass().execute();

}
public class User {
    public String mail;
    public String password;
}
public class myasyncclass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create a very simple REST adapter which points the GitHub API endpoint.
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setServer(API_URL)
        .build();
        Login login = restAdapter.create(Login.class);
        User user=new User();
        user.mail="ttete";
        user.password="tett";
        Contributor1 contributors = login.mu(user,new Callback<Contributor1>() {

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {                  
                System.out.println("failure, error: " + error);
            }

            @Override
            public void success(Contributor1 result, Response arg1) {
                System.out.println("success, result: " + result);

            }
        });
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

This is my entire class .But i am getting the following error

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Method mu may only have return type or Callback as last argument, not both.

What should i do overcome this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This interface definition is wrong as per the error.

```
interface Login {
    @POST("/testapp/")
    Contributor1 mu(@Body User user,Callback<Contributor1> callBack);

}
```

You should modify it to

```
interface Login {
    @POST("/testapp/")
    Contributor1 mu(@Body User user);

}
```

Since now it does not have a callback, you should be able to call it synchronously.